# Why is 'git add --al' with single 'l' working?

Tags: git, git-bash

In git bash I typed `git add --al` (with single *'l'*) by mistake, and it worked.
From [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--A) I can't see the option with single 'l' letter.

I Searched on google and couldn't find any explanation.

Not important, just for curiosity: Now whenever I type `--all` I can't stop myself thinking "*If I'm wasting my time with typing second 'l'*" :)

#Git options abbreviation

Comment: If there's no match of options, `git` simply ignores it, so `git add --al` = `git add`

Comment: "*If there's no match of options, git simply ignores it*" -> I tried `git log --al` it throws "Unrecognized argument: --al", but not for `git add --al`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abbreviating long form options is usually allowed, if the result is unambigous, according [to the conventions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcli#_description) (emphasis mine):

> Many commands allow a long option `--option` to be abbreviated only to their unique prefix (e.g. **if there is no other option whose name begins with `opt`**, you may be able to spell `--opt` to invoke the `--option` flag), but you should fully spell them out when writing your scripts; later versions of Git may introduce a new option whose name shares the same prefix, e.g. `--optimize`, to make a short prefix that used to be unique no longer unique.

Since (as of now) `--al` only prefixes a single legal long option for `git-add`, it will be accepted as `--all`. Theoretically even `gid add --a` could work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought at first too, but I tried `git add --al` and `git log --al`.... why is there a difference? Shouldn't `git log --al` also be equated to `git log --all`?

Comment: Because `git-log` has `--all` and `--all-match`, so `--al` is no longer a unique prefix.

Comment: Oh damn! I considered it but somehow missed `--all-match`, good catch, thank you :-)